# Не прерывается QThread

Tags: qt, c++

Почему-то не прерывается поток при вызове thread->exit(0);

Сократил к минимуму.

Есть класс Worker:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker(std::shared_ptr<ImageHandler>& handler);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<ImageHandler> handler;

public slots:
    void work()
    {
        this->handler->startHandler();
        emit finished(this);
    }

signals:
    void finished(Worker* worker);
};
```

Он находится в потоке.

Клаcс Processes управляет множеством потоков.

```
class Processes : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    void addThread(std::shared_ptr<Worker>& worker);
    void runThread(std::shared_ptr<Worker>& worker);

public slots:
    void removeThread(Worker* worker);

private:
    QMap<std::shared_ptr<QThread>, std::shared_ptr<Worker>> processes;

signals:
    void handled(Worker* worker);
};

void Processes::addThread(std::shared_ptr<Worker>& worker)
{
    std::shared_ptr<QThread> thread(new QThread());

    worker->moveToThread(thread.get());
    connect(thread.get(), SIGNAL(started()), worker.get(), SLOT(work()));

    this->processes.insert(thread, worker);
}

void Processes::runThread(std::shared_ptr<Worker> &worker)
{
    std::shared_ptr<QThread> thread = processes.key(worker);
    thread->start();
}

void Processes::removeThread(Worker* worker)
{
    std::shared_ptr<QThread> thread;

    // Нахожу нужный поток.
    // ...

    thread.get()->exit(0);
    // Но он не прервался.
    this->processes.remove(thread); // Ошибка. Удаляется рабочий поток.
}
```

Далее функция инициализации объекта класса Worker и запуск потока

```
void MainWindow::on_actionAdd_Noise_triggered()
{
    std::shared_ptr<ImageHandler> handler(new AddNoiseHandler());    
    std::shared_ptr<Worker> worker(new Worker(handler));

    // Поле класса MainWindow: Processes processes;
    processes.addThread(worker);

    connect(worker.get(), SIGNAL(finished(Worker*)), this, SLOT(updateAfterHandle(Worker*)));
    processes.runThread(worker);
}

void MainWindow::updateAfterHandle(Worker* worker)
{
    // ...
    // Вызывает ошибку
    this->processes.removeThread(value);
}
```

Comment: @vaddemgen: Ну да. Так везде: вы не убиваете thread, вы сигнализируете ему, что он больше не нужен, и он должен сам умереть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашел в Qt:
"Note that deleting a QThread object will not stop the execution of the thread it represents. Deleting a running QThread (i.e. isFinished() returns false) will probably result in a program crash. You can wait() on a thread to make sure that it has finished."